# MS Access Pulling last 12 digits of barcode

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I changed scan guns recently from a FedEx scan gun, to a Wasp scan gun. Now when I scan a FedEx label, it gives me a 24 character tracking, and I only need the last 12 digits. I will also be scanning UPS labels and they are alphanumeric. Is there any way to truncate all but the last 12 digits of an all numeric barcode scanned into a text box?

My current code has me leaving off the leading zeros, but if I could just get the last 12 digits, I wouldn't need that piece of code.

Current Code:

```
Dim strIn As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim iLen As Integer
strIn = Me.txt_Track.Value
iLen = Len(strIn)
For i = 1 To iLen
For i = 1 To iLen
    If InStr(strIn, "0") = 1 Then
        strIn = Mid(strIn, 2)
    End If
Next i
CurrentDb.Execute
            "INSERT INTO TrackNum_Table(TrackingNum_TrackNum) " & _
            "VALUES ('" & strIn & "')"
```

Comment: Will the last 12 positions always be numeric, or can they contain letters?

Comment: Lets assume, all UPS labels we receive are alphanumeric, we would want to keep all of those. Lets now assume all just numeric barcodes scanned are FedEx, lets truncate these and grab the last 12 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved this.

```
Dim strIn As String
Dim strOut As String
strIn = Me.txt_Track.Value
Numeric = IsNumeric(strIn)
If Numeric = True Then
    strOut = Right(strIn, 12)
Else
    strOut = strIn
End If
CurrentDb.Execute _
            "INSERT INTO TrackNum_Table(TrackingNum_TrackNum) " & _
            "VALUES ('" & strOut & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

*Right* will do that:

```
Code = Right(strIn, 12)
```

Comment: How can I use this only in the case of only numeric barcodes, because typically FedEx only sends numeric. UPS will typically send alphanumeric codes.

Comment: You found out, I can see.